# PHP Fatal error: Cannot break/continue

Tags: php, foreach, if-statement, break

```
if (isset($errors))  
{  
foreach ($errors as $error)  
  {  
    echo $error;  
  }    
}  
else {break 2;}  
// some more code
```

Outputs:

```
Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 2 levels
```

I tried `break 1`, it didn't work either.

Comment: There are no loops in your code. Please post full code.

Comment: Could you please explain the context in which this code runs?

Comment: There is no need for break there because when the if fails it will continue going on regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (isset($errors))  
{  
foreach ($errors as $error)  
  {  
    echo $error;  
  }    
}
```

No need to use break as you seem to want to end on the else condition. just use the above code for your errors, it will be skipped if no errors. No need for break

Answer (score 4):

Break ends the execution within a  foreach, for, while, do-while or switch structure..

```
if (isset($errors))  
{  
foreach ($errors as $error)  
  {  
    echo $error;  
  }    
}  
else {break 2;} //there is no loop here!
```

Comment: removed the false statement that break does not take an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `break` not followed with any number. But break is helpless outside of a loop / block.